# WinAPI C++ - Do subclassed controls still send notifications to their parent?

Tags: c++, winapi, notifications, controls, subclass

I am making an edit-control wrapper class. The edit-control around which the class wraps is sub-classed so that the virtual methods (or 'events', such as `virtual void OnChange()`) can be overridden. My only question is, if I handle, let's say, the `EN_CHANGE` notification, in the controls subclass procedure, can the user still handle the `EN_UPDATE` notification in the parent windows procedure? Or does subclassing a control mean ALL of the notifications are handled by the controls new window procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages that your subclass does not process should be given to `CallWindowProc(original window procedure)` so that the default for the control will happen instead.

That said, the `EN_` notifications don't get sent to the control, they get sent to the parent directly.

Comment: Unhandled window messages should be sent to the control's original window procedure, not DefWindowProc.

Comment: @PeterRuderman and Raymond Chen, thanks for setting me straight. Most of my Windows experience is with MFC which tries too hard to hide these details from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle an EN_CHANGE notification inside the control's window proceedure.  This notification is sent directly to the parent window.

For other window messages, it's up to you where they will be handled.  Usually, the window manager sends messages only to a single window.  If you handle the message in your window procedure, then no one else will see it.

Comment: Technically that's not true. E.g. with MFC you could use [message reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeah46xd(v=vs.80).aspx) to handle notifications in child instead of parent.

Comment: We're talking about the Win32 API, not MFC. MFC is able to perform this trick because it controls every window in the app. The original poster might be able to do something similar, but he can't achieve it just by subclassing the edit control.